# JSF POST without "confirm for resubmision"

Tags: java, jsf, rest, post

I have a jsf form that calls POST rest service. When I hit the F5 key Chrome notifies me that it will recall that service. I want to avoid that. I want just to inform user that calling service was successfully executed. Also when I go to another page in my application, if I hit F5 this service will be called either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the service being called via an AJAX request, or are you submitting the form? If the latter, most browsers will notify you of that any time you try to refresh a page to prevent you from accidentally performing an action multiple times. The best way around this is to have your application perform a redirect after the form submission is successfully processed. More info here: https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/post_redirect_get_and_jsf

Answer (score 0):

Normally, POST data are stored in the HTTP header, and you can't destroy it when you refresh the page, but it's automatically destroyed when you go to another page, unless you use class attributes on the servlet requested !?